# Ruby recurse directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, recursion

I am trying to recurse a directory, and all its subdirectories. I dont want to use "Find" or any other way except this one:

```
task :locate do

    Dir.chdir(Dir.pwd+"/public/servers_info/config/deploy/")
    puts "Current Directory is: "+ Dir.pwd
    dir = Dir.pwd

    def get_information(dir)

        Dir.foreach(".") {|f|
            next if f == '.' or f == '..'

            if File.directory? f
                puts f
                #puts Dir.pwd+"/"+f
                get_information(Dir.pwd+"/"+f)
            else
                puts "Not Directory"
            end         
            }
    end

    get_information(dir)

end
```

I am pretty sure that it will work, I just dont know why it get stucks in the first directory! It enters the base directory, checks is the file is a directory or not, and then runs the SAME function again. But it doesnt! it gets stuck on the first folder and I get an error! Any help?

Comment: Why are you passing in `dir` to your method and then never use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is always looking at the "current" (.) directory. Your get_information method passes in a value bound to `dir`, which you never use.

Since you never use that parameter, you never change directories.

What you're trying to do is easier with `Dir.glob`, but if you're wedded to your solution, you'll need to change `Dir.foreach(".")` to something like `Dir.foreach(dir)`.

**Edited to add**: If all you want is to print out a list of subdirectories, I would do

```
puts Dir.glob('*/**').select { |f| File.directory? f}
```

This includes only directories. If you want pretty close to the exact output of your existing code, I would do something like:

```
puts Dir.glob('*/**').map { |f| File.directory?(f)? f : "Not a Directory" }
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out `Dir.glob`. Docs [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Dir.html#method-c-glob)

Comment: so instead of "Dir.foreach" I should use "Dir.glob" ?

Comment: I dont wanna change my code, my logic seems to be correct, I don't know why it doesnt work

Comment: Yeah. So you won't have to write `get_information` recursively, and treat it as a loop.